# Macro keeps crashing need to speed it up or rewrite it, excel vba 50,000 lines of data

Tags: vba

Trying to speed up a macro that runs over 50,000 lines !

I have two ways of performing the same vba macro

```
    Sub deleteCommonValue()
Dim aRow, bRow As Long
Dim colB_MoreFirst, colB_LessFirst, colB_Second, colC_MoreFirst, colC_LessFirst, colC_Second As Integer
Dim colD_First, colD_Second As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

aRow = 2
bRow = 3

colB_MoreFirst = Range("B" & aRow).Value + 0.05
colB_LessFirst = Range("B" & aRow).Value - 0.05
colB_Second = Range("B" & bRow).Value
colC_MoreFirst = Range("C" & aRow).Value + 0.05
colC_LessFirst = Range("C" & aRow).Value - 0.05
colC_Second = Range("C" & bRow).Value
colD_First = Range("D" & aRow).Value
colD_Second = Range("D" & bRow).Value

Do

If colB_Second <= colB_MoreFirst And colB_Second >= colB_LessFirst Then

    If colC_Second <= colC_MoreFirst And colC_Second >= colC_LessFirst Then

        If colD_Second = colD_First Or colD_Second > colD_First Then
            Range(bRow & ":" & bRow).Delete
           'bRow delete, assign new value to bRow
           colB_Second = Range("B" & bRow).Value
           colC_Second = Range("C" & bRow).Value
           colD_Second = Range("D" & bRow).Value
           '-----------------------------------------------------
        Else
            Range(aRow & ":" & aRow).Delete
            bRow = aRow + 1

            'aRow value deleted, assign new value to aRow and bRow
            colB_MoreFirst = Range("B" & aRow).Value + 0.05
            colB_LessFirst = Range("B" & aRow).Value - 0.05
            colB_Second = Range("B" & bRow).Value
            colC_MoreFirst = Range("C" & aRow).Value + 0.05
            colC_LessFirst = Range("C" & aRow).Value - 0.05
            colC_Second = Range("C" & bRow).Value
            colD_First = Range("D" & aRow).Value
            colD_Second = Range("D" & bRow).Value
            '-----------------------------------------------------
        End If

    Else
        bRow = bRow + 1
        'Assign new value to bRow
        colB_Second = Range("B" & bRow).Value
        colC_Second = Range("C" & bRow).Value
        colD_Second = Range("D" & bRow).Value
        '-----------------------------------------------------
    End If

Else
    bRow = bRow + 1
    'Assign new value to bRow
    colB_Second = Range("B" & bRow).Value
    colC_Second = Range("C" & bRow).Value
    colD_Second = Range("D" & bRow).Value
    '-----------------------------------------------------
End If
If IsEmpty(Range("D" & bRow).Value) = True Then
    aRow = aRow + 1
    bRow = aRow + 1
    'finish compare aRow, assign new value to aRow and bRow
    colB_MoreFirst = Range("B" & aRow).Value + 0.05
    colB_LessFirst = Range("B" & aRow).Value - 0.05
    colB_Second = Range("B" & bRow).Value
    colC_MoreFirst = Range("C" & aRow).Value + 0.05
    colC_LessFirst = Range("C" & aRow).Value - 0.05
    colC_Second = Range("C" & bRow).Value
    colD_First = Range("D" & aRow).Value
    colD_Second = Range("D" & bRow).Value
    '-----------------------------------------------------

End If
Loop Until IsEmpty(Range("D" & aRow).Value) = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = False

End Sub
```

or

```
Sub deleteCommonValue()
Dim aRow, bRow As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
aRow = 2
bRow = 3

Do
If Range("B" & bRow).Value <= (Range("B" & aRow).Value + 0.05) _
    And Range("B" & bRow).Value >= (Range("B" & aRow).Value - 0.05) Then

    If Range("C" & bRow).Value <= (Range("C" & aRow).Value + 0.05) _
        And Range("C" & bRow).Value >= (Range("C" & aRow).Value - 0.05) Then

        If Range("D" & bRow).Value = (Range("D" & aRow).Value) _
            Or Range("D" & bRow).Value > (Range("D" & aRow).Value) Then
            Range(bRow & ":" & bRow).Delete
        Else
            Range(aRow & ":" & aRow).Delete
            bRow = aRow + 1
            Range("A" & aRow).Select
        End If

    Else
        bRow = bRow + 1
        Range("A" & bRow).Select

    End If

Else
    bRow = bRow + 1
    Range("A" & bRow).Select
End If
If IsEmpty(Range("D" & bRow).Value) = True Then
    aRow = aRow + 1
    bRow = aRow + 1
End If
Loop Until IsEmpty(Range("D" & aRow).Value) = True

End Sub
```

I dont know if my best option will be to split the rows into multiple sheets?

Comment: Creating the result someplace else instead of modifying the input will usually be faster.

Comment: My first thought on your second macro: Don't use `select`

Comment: @Joel: if you would write your rules in your question, I can try to build a solution that will do the task without a loop (either with AutoFilter and Sort or with SpecialCells maybe)

Comment: Please add some more information to your question so that people don't need to read all the code to see what you're trying to do. A brief summary of what you're trying to accomplish, and a summary of what the logical flow of each different macro does, would help give context to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would read all the values into a 2D variant array, like so:

```
Dim Vals() as variant
Vals = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value
```

Then I'd loop through all the values in the array rather than accessing the ranges over and over again.  I'd build a collection or list of rows to delete, then just delete them in a single go.

That should help to speed things up.  I think you'd be able to read 50k rows into memory okay, but you may have to do a couple thousand at a time, rather than try to fit them all into a single array...

Comment: It is hard to tell without a description, but it seems to be only columns A:D of interest, so rather than `UsedRange` this could be reduced using either `Intersect` or `Range("A1").CurrentRegion`. Also seems to be examining pairs of rows at a time (I may be wrong). So could loop through the area in steps of 2, storing just the current 2 rows in a Variant array. But.. a description would help.